# Set cookie for ONLY two different subdomains

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to set a cookie that will be available to `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com` but **not** `sub3.example.com`.

I know making the `domain` value `.example.com` will open the value to all subdomains, but I want it to be limited to just these two. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A cookie can only be set for its own domain or an ancestor domain. It's not possible to set a domain for a domain related in some other way, and there's no exclusion lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to store data based on subdomain. A workaround idea could be to store the subdomain as part of the data and let your application run the behavior based on it.

**1)** Get the subdomain:

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = parts.shift();
```

**2)** Then you could save that subdomain as part of the data you're saving

```
localStorage.setItem(subdomain, 'someData');
```

**3)** Then run a conditional when you need to operate only on a certain subdomain.

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = parts.shift();

if (subdomain !== "sub3") {
    // run your functionality
    var data = storage.getItem(subdomain);
}
```

That way, your 1) storage is available on `sub1` and `sub2`, 2) but the functionality doesn't run on `sub3`