# Can I write cookie for subdomain2.foo.com from subdomain1.foo.com

Tags: cookies

I want to share cookies for only certain subdomains. So thinking of doing the operation in the title. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookie for ONLY two different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602778/set-cookie-for-only-two-different-subdomains)

Comment: not exactly. that uses localstorage.

Comment: The key relevant part was that you can't do it with cookies. You could set a `foo.com` cookie, but that wouldn't fit the "only certain subdomains" part of your question.

Comment: add that as an answer and i may accept it.

Answer (score -1):

### By default no, but with a bit of code, yes.

You can do That using the Domain property of cookies, setting it up to foo.com

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue; domain=foo.com; path=/";
```

That way, "myCookie" will be available for all domains that contain "foo.com"